# Doing a Laravel tutorial, getting "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sdbd_todo.migrations' doesn't exist"

Tags: php, laravel, refresh, migrate

Working through [this tutorial](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2013/12/creating-a-basic-todo-application-with-laravel-4-part-1/), I'm down to the following step:

> You should now be able to call migrate as many times as you want and it’ll work:
>
> `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Upon running that command, I get the following errors:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sdbd_todo.migrations' doesn't exist (SQL: select max(`batch`) as aggregate
>     from `migrations`)
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sdbd_todo.migrations' doesn't exist

Googling about the error (obviously without the site-specific table name) doesn't find any answers that seem to help.

Full disclosure: I'm new to Laravel, and to Stack Overflow for that matter, please go easy on me. :)

Comment: Well do you have a `migrations` table in your database?

Comment: According to the tutorial, running the migrate:refresh command should populate the database.

Comment: Tried "php artisan migrate" and that appears to have worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`php artisan migrate` will create the migrations table for you if it does not exist yet, then run any and all migrations that have not been run yet.

`php artisan migrate:refresh` is for resetting all existing migrations, then running them again. It expects the migrations table to already exist.

You can use `php artisan list` to list all available Artisan commands and their descriptions to learn more about these and other migration-related commands.

Comment: Thank you, that has helped my understanding.